# How to replace list of channels to grid list?

Tags: android, gridview, android-gridview, android-tv, leanback

I have a TV app. I see list of channels and I made it be like a row. But now I want to rewrite it to be like a grid. I'm trying to set grid presenter, but it doesn't work it says I must implement MainFragmentAdapterProvider. And all tips from tutorials doesn't work too, I can't figure out what's a problem. Maybe there's another presenter for it?

```
    public class ChannelsFragment extends RowsFragment implements OnItemViewClickedListener {

    private ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
    //private ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;
    private IServiceControl mServiceControl;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mServiceControl = ((A4TVTestApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getServiceControl();

        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
        setOnItemViewClickedListener(this);

        createRows();
    }

    private void createRows() {
//        VerticalGridPresenter presenter = new VerticalGridPresenter();
//        presenter.setNumberOfColumns(4);
//        setGridPresenter(presenter);
//        setTitle(getString(R.string.scanned_channels));
//
//        setOnItemViewClickedListener(this);
//
//        try {
//            for (int i = 0; i < mServiceControl.getServiceListCount(0); i++) {
//                mRowsAdapter.add(mServiceControl.getServiceDescriptor(0, i).getName());
//            }
//        } catch (RemoteException e) {
//            e.printStackTrace();
//        }
        ChannelsRowItemPresenter presenter = new ChannelsRowItemPresenter();

        ArrayObjectAdapter firstRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenter);
        ArrayObjectAdapter secondRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenter);
        ArrayObjectAdapter thirdRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenter);
        ArrayObjectAdapter fourthRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenter);

        try {
            int count = mServiceControl.getServiceListCount(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i += 4) {
                firstRowAdapter.add(mServiceControl.getServiceDescriptor(0, i));
                secondRowAdapter.add(mServiceControl.getServiceDescriptor(0, i + 1));
                thirdRowAdapter.add(mServiceControl.getServiceDescriptor(0, i + 2));
                fourthRowAdapter.add(mServiceControl.getServiceDescriptor(0, i + 3));
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(new HeaderItem(getString(R.string.scanned_channels)),
                firstRowAdapter));

        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(secondRowAdapter));
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(thirdRowAdapter));
        mRowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(fourthRowAdapter));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                              RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
        ServiceDescriptor serviceDescriptor = (ServiceDescriptor) item;
        ChannelActivity.startActivity(getActivity(), serviceDescriptor.getLCN());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried extending VerticalGridFragment?

There is an example in the leanback sample:
https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/ui/VerticalGridFragment.java

Your implementation should look similar to this below. `MyPresenter` should be a subclass of Presenter, such as CardPresenter in leanback which delegates/manages a view like ImageCardView or your custom card view by extending BaseCardView. If you have more dynamic content, subclass PresenterSelector instead so that each Card can be different.

```
public class ChannelFragment extends android.support.v17.leanback.app.VerticalGridFragment
implements OnItemViewClickedListener {

    private static final int NUM_COLUMNS = 5;

    private final ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter;
    private IServiceControl mServiceControl;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new MyPresenter());
        mServiceControl = ((A4TVTestApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getServiceControl();
        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);
        setOnItemViewClickedListener(this);

        createRows();
    }

    private void createRows() {
        VerticalGridPresenter gridPresenter = new VerticalGridPresenter();
        gridPresenter.setNumberOfColumns(NUM_COLUMNS);
        // This is the method that will help you get a grid layout.
        setGridPresenter(gridPresenter);

        setOnItemViewClickedListener(this);

        try {
            for (int i = 0; i < mServiceControl.getServiceListCount(0); i++) {
                mRowsAdapter.add(i);
            }
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, Object item,
                      RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {
         ChannelActivity.startActivity(getActivity(), (int) item);
    }
}
```

Comment: References
1:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/Presenter.html

2:https://github.com/googlesamples/androidtv-Leanback/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/tvleanback/presenter/CardPresenter.java

3:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ImageCardView.html

4:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/BaseCardView.html

5:https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/PresenterSelector.html

Answer (score 4):

There is also a [method on ListRowAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v17/leanback/widget/ListRowPresenter.html#setNumRows(int)) to enable having multiple rows per row.

```
ListRowPresenter presenter = new ListRowPresenter()
presenter.setNumRows(4)
ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenter);
```

This is better than using a VerticalGridFragment depending on if you still want the category header.